# Cannot run GridDB docker in Fixed List mode

Tags: griddb

Running GridDB docker in fixed list mode e.g.

```
docker run -dt --network="host" -e NOTIFICATION_MEMBER=1 griddb/griddb:latest
```

leads to the following error:

```
Fixed List mode
Execution failed. See message logs
/start-griddb.sh: line 94: exec: griddb: not found
```

Had no issue running in multicast mode.

Answer (score 0):

the fix is actually to increase the amount of wait time in the start-griddb.sh script provided by the griddb dockerhub image.

You can see a working example here: https://github.com/griddbnet/IoT-Project-Codebase/tree/main/griddb-server

I believe  the developers are going to be merging the fix soon